# How to import contacts saved from Gmail?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am looking for a way to import contacts that are saved to a persons gmail account using flutter. I know of the contacts_service package you can use but that only imports from local storage as far as I have tested. Is there a way to get contacts from gmail?